# Erro Grave na linguagem PHP

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Descobri um BUG na linguagem php e estou buscando se tem uma explicação logica para isso, tenho o seguinte Código:

```
<?php
    echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
?>
```

E o resultado mostrado é: 7. Porque isso? seria um bug do php?

façam o teste: http://phpio.net/s/ryn

Comment: This is not a bug it's a feature. Isso é um float, com arredondamento. Essa pergunta é uma duplicata.

Comment: Isso não é exclusivo de PHP, e sim um problema de ponto flutuante: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Pode e mandar o link @Inkeliz

Comment: PHP é utilizada por milhões de pessoas, todos os dias e há vários anos. Se houvesse algum bug desse tipo, teria sido corrigido há muito tempo. Antes de achar que algum comportamento estranho é um bug, faça uma pesquisa sobre por que essas coisas acontecem. Você vai aprender bastante sobre coisas que nem imaginava existirem e se tornará um programador melhor ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sobre a sua questão a expressão ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10) deve avaliar para 8.

No entanto, a saída da expressão no script é avaliada em 7 porque o mecanismo PHP armazena o valor da expressão internamente como 7.999999 em vez de 7.

Quando o valor fracionado é convertido em um número inteiro, o mecanismo PHP simplesmente trunca a parte fracionada.

Quando o valor é convertido em int, PHP simplesmente trunca a parte fracionada, resultando em um erro bastante significativo (12,5%, para ser exato).

Answer (score 1):

Não é um BUG do PHP logicamente, e sim por você está fazendo um cast (int) logo valores com ponto flutuante são arredondados para o mais ou menos significativo.